# Wait for addClass to execute

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with jquery. What I am trying to do is make the same button do two different actions depending on the class. Seems simple but I am stuck. What i have is this:

```
$(".edit-comment").click(function(){
    $(".edit-comment").removeClass("active-edit");
    $(".comment-input").removeClass("active-edit");
    $(this).prev().children().addClass("active-edit");
    $(this).addClass("active-edit");
    $(this).prev().children().focus();
 });

 $(document).on("click", ".active-edit", function() {
     console.log("edit");
 });
```

The issue with this is I get the console log immediately on the first click, and I don`t need that, when 'edit-comment' is clicked it should only addClass and removeClass, and then on the second click it should log 'edit'.

I tried with javascript setTimeOut, callbacks but it didn`t work.

EDIT:

Sharing some html:

```
<tr class="alert-comment">
 <td colspan="6"><input type="text" value="" class="comment-input" /></td>
 <td class="edit-comment" title="Click the text to edit"><span class="edit-comment-icon"></span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You have an `.active-edit` in your html in the first run, is for this that click is executing. Provide your html, maybe there's another solution better than this

Comment: You might try to `return false` in your first click function to prevent the event propagation. The event is likely bubbling up to the document and triggering the other click function.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude html shared

Comment: @MarcBaumbach return false didn`t work, when I add return false the first click does what it should be the 2nd does not work at all

Answer (score 0):

You might want to move your second click function inside the click function that is required to run first. ie:

```
$(".edit-comment").click(function(){
    $(".edit-comment").removeClass("active-edit");
    $(".comment-input").removeClass("active-edit");
    $(this).prev().children().addClass("active-edit");
    $(this).addClass("active-edit");
    $(this).prev().children().focus();

    $('.parent-container').on("click", ".active-edit", function() {
        console.log("edit");
    });
});
```

That is certainly not a very pretty solution. If you share some html, someone could point you in a better direction.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".active-edit"` is a *delegated` event.  It's actually bound to the `document` and just checks if the `event.target` is `.active-edit` or not.  This solution would re-bind that event over and over, thus running `console.log("edit");` multiple times on each click.

Comment: You are right, some parent container should be used as a selector. replacing `on` with `one` might resolve this issue as well. However, as stated some html would be useful to give a higher quality answer.